# Previous activity is not finishing after using finish()

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-linking

I did a deep link where the user can choose either app he wants to launch. But for some reason after the user selected the app and wants to change to another app it doesn't work because when i launch again the activity it's from the previous app and not the new one.
I think there is something with this method because it looks like SplashActivity it's above the new activity and i need to kill it. I tried changing also SplashActivity to my MainActivity but same issue.

```
 private fun initMainScreen() {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SplashActivity::class.java)
        intent
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        applicationContext.startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call finish() before you start activity.

```
 private fun initMainScreen() {
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SplashActivity::class.java)
    finish()
    intent
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
    applicationContext.startActivity(intent)
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question but that doesn't work unfortunately